# How to use session variable in file target with NLog?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration-files, nlog

I would like to put each session in different folder :
`${basedir}/logs/session/2016-08-11.log`

But I don't found how to use session variable in NLog.config like

```xml
<targets>
   <target xsi:type="File" name="Example" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${aspnet-session:Variable=Login}/${longdate}.log" layout="${message}" />
</targets>
```

I don't know if it's possible ? Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET 4 you should include [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web) NuGet package

For ASP.NET Core you need [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/) and the following config (not needed with non-core)

In your nlog.config:

```
  <extensions>
    <!--enable NLog.Web for ASP.NET Core-->
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>
```

In your startup.cs

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //add NLog to ASP.NET Core
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();

        //add NLog.Web
        app.AddNLogWeb();
```

in project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rtm-alpha4",
    "NLog.Web.AspNetCore": "4.2.3"
},
```

Comment: Thanks Julian, but I can't do same configuration as you mentioned because I don't have startup.cs and project.json in my project. I tried to add Owin Nuget package in order to add startup.cs, but IApplicationBuilder, IHostingEnvironment and AddNLog() have not been recognize :-( Any idea ?

Comment: What platform / OS / .NET version are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS2015, .NET 4.5.2 with Windows 10

Comment: ASP.NET 4? ASP.NET Core?